# Computed property "username" was assigned to but it has no setter

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I get bellow error in my browser.

> Computed property "username" was assigned to but it has no setter.

in my `computed` code is bellow:

```
  username:{
    get(){return this.$store.state.user_data.username}
  },
```

you see I get the `username` by `this.$store.state.user_data.username`.

so I do not have a `set_username` in mutations for commit, so there I do not give a `set(){}`.

How to avoid this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The default computed properties is getter only ([document](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter)). You can change to:

```
computed: {
  username () {
    return this.$store.state.user_data.username
  }
}
```

You might want to use [mapState](https://vuex.vuejs.org/state.html#the-mapstate-helper) helper of vuex

Comment: the `username:{
    return this.$store.state.user_data.username
  }` will get error.

Comment: do you mean is `username(){}` ?

Comment: Yes, it should be a function

Comment: He's getting _"Computed property "username" was assigned to but it has no setter."_ meaning that somewhere he's probably setting `this.username` or using `v-model="username"`. Nothing to do with the implementation of the computed.

Comment: what if i'm not using vuex, just vue